# How can I configure child with multiple parents in app.module

Tags: angular, angular6, angular5

I have 1 child component and I want to define routings on app.module.
    What can I achieve this with best practice code?

In the code above, Is it ok to define `child1` on sub of `ParentComponent2`?

```
path: 'parent-component', //<---- parent component declared here
  component: ParentComponent1,
  children: [ //<---- child components declared 
    {
      path: 'child-one',
      component: ChildOneComponent
    },
    {
      path: 'child-two',
      component: ChildTwoComponent
    }
  ],
  path: 'parent-component2', //<---- parent component declared here
  component: ParentComponent2
```

Is it ok me to write codes like this

```
path: 'parent-component', //<---- parent component declared here
      component: ParentComponent1,
      children: [ //<---- child components declared 
        {
          path: 'child-one',
          component: ChildOneComponent
        },
        {
          path: 'child-two',
          component: ChildTwoComponent
        }
      ],
  path: 'parent-component2', //<---- parent component declared here
      component: ParentComponent2,
      children: [ //<---- child components declared 
        {
          path: 'child-one',
          component: ChildOneComponent
        },
        {
          path: 'child-two',
          component: ChildTwoComponent
        }
      ],
```

Comment: What is the question? If it works, then yes, it's okey to do so!

Comment: A child can only have one parent. Please specify your issue a bit more, right now it's way too broad to be answered.

Comment: If It is true , the question would be wrong, 1 child must have 1 parent and can not have more than 1 parent , you mean?

Answer (score 0):

If what you are trying to achieve is Lazy Loading feature of angular  , then the above code is perfect. childoneComponent and childTwoComponent is loaded only when 
1] You are currently in ParentComponent1 and you navigate to "child-one" or "child-two"
2] Directly navigate the "child-one" or "child-two" without visiting the parent component

Also it shall be noted that the parent of childoneComponent is ParentComponent1  which can have a parent component "SuperParentComponent" itself. Hence , you can build a tree a components which are lazy loaded

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on if there is a UseCase for this specific behaviour. But to me this sounds as if your parent components are not really the place to put ist unless you would want to pass data specific to these parents.
It would be quite interesting if you could elaborate on what oyu try to achieve with this.

On a "best practice" basis I can't see anything wrong with it, if and only if you are trying to do something like the above, otherwise I would recommend the usage of an independent path.

Comment: In fact I have a  component and in this component I want to use another component.  It will be nested components. I want to use selector or nested component on main component. Do I have to define children for this purpose or when should I define children?